# InputStreamReader on socket not reading POST request completely

Tags: java, sockets

I have the following code:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2351);

Socket s = ss.accept();
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
writer = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
writer.flush();

cbuf = new char[buf_length];
in.read(cbuf);
inputLine = new String(cbuf);
```

I ran four consecutive sends to my server and when I debug the above code it runs correctly three times. The other time the following is my inputLine that is read from the socket:

```
POST /record HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset="utf-8";action=""
Accept: application/soap+xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.1.5-b03-
Host: localhost:2351
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2197
```

And the content is just 2197 whitespaces instead of a 2197 length content. Its really weird and I am stuck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a problem on the client side - please post relevant code from there. Also, you really need to take into consideration the actual bytes read in the call to `in.read(cbuf)`, instead of assuming it actually fills the buffer.

Comment: What do you see if you examine the data stream with Wireshark?   If the data is being transmitted as blanks, the problem is at the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to make EJP's answer more concrete. Instead of

```
n.read(cbuf);
inputLine = new String(cbuf);
```

You need to do something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int charsRead;
while ((charsRead = n.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
    sb.append(cbuf, 0, charsRead);
}
inputLine = sb.toString();
```

This may not be the answer to the question you are asking, but it is definitely a bug in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that in.read() fills the buffer. You can't assume that. See the Javadoc. It is only obliged to read at least one character, or return -1 because of EOS.

Comment: But the problem is that the in.read() has stuff in the buffer. The HTTP header is being read completely. The content length is said to be 2197 meaning it is supposed to have 2197 characters from the HTTP request that is coming in. Its only that the buffer does not have these specific characters.

Comment: @OVB As you are ignoring the value returned by read(), you *cannot possibly know* how much data was actually read.

Answer (score 0):

@EJP: I rewrote my code and it is finally working. The problem was that the in.read() was reading only the header of the POST request in the first attempt in some cases. I had to check the content length field and if it was less than the number of characters read as you pointed out, I had to do the in.read() once again to get the request completely. Thanks all you guys!